# Home page won't load without 'index.php'

Tags: url, config, install, index

On a fresh install of *Craft* 2.3.2644, using the hostname alone, `example.com` returns an error, "*The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred*".

If I include `/index.php` (`example.com/index.php`), then the expected `index` template is returned, displaying the "Welcome to..." entry.

However, `example.com/news` returns the `news` template correctly, even without `index.php` in the URI.

- Craft 2.3.2644
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5

The `web.config` file included with the *Craft* install is present at web root.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, IIS doesn't include `index.php` as a default document when looking for a page to load in a directory, but only things like `index.html`, `index.htm`, `deafult.html`, etc.

[Here's how to change it.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I already added `index.php` to the default document list and it's first in the priority order.

Comment: Can you check the IIS error logs? Should have the underlying internal server error message there.

Comment: I don't think I have direct access to server logs. I'll have to check with the hosting provider to see if that's something I can get.

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error  The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: I'm guessing IIS can't read the `web.config` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620654/500-19-internal-server-error-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-t and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: After a little work with the hosting provider, this has been resolved. It appears some of the statements in `web.config` were causing conflicts (either the `urlCompression` or `defaultDocument` sections). I removed those to no apparent ill effect, leaving only the rewrite. All is working for now. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, @PhilipJones.